# Dual list in asp .net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a dual list in mvc 4. In post method I am not able to get the model data.
I can drag and drop an item from one list to another and on submit i need data in my post method. But in model.SelectedColumns I m getting null.What am I doing wrong ?

here is my code--

model :

```
public class Columns
{
    public List<string> SelectedColumns { set; get; }
    public List<string> RemainingColumns { set; get; }
}
```

view :

```
@Html.BeginForm("AddRemoveColumns", "DashBoard",FormMethod.Post){
<div style="float: left">
    <h2>
        AddRemoveColumns</h2>
    <ol id="SelectedColumns" class="connectedSortable">
        @foreach (var item in Model.SelectedColumns)
        {

            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>@item
            </li>
        }
    </ol>
</div>
<div style="float: right">
    <ol id="RemainingColumns" class="connectedSortable">
        @foreach (var item in Model.RemainingColumns)
        {

            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>@item
            </li>
        }
    </ol>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
}
```

script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
   $(function () { $("#SelectedColumns, #RemainingColumns").sortable({ 
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable" }).disableSelection(); 
   });

</script>
```

controller :

```
public ActionResult AddRemoveColumns()
{
    Columns columns = DbAccess.getSelectedColumns();
    return View(columns);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRemoveColumns(Columns model)
{
    Columns columns = new Columns();
    columns.SelectedColumns = model.SelectedColumns;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just displaying your list using html tags and you have not binded your list with any control that's why you are getting null value, If you want to use form posting then you have to bind you model with MVC controls as below:

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedColumns, new { @id = "SelectedColumns" })
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RemainingColumns , new { @id = "RemainingColumns " })

Thanks

Comment: I dont want to use @Html.ListBoxFor becoz i m using jquery sortable. So is there any way of getting the modified data of my lists in my controller ?...Thanks for reply

Comment: Simply you can use $.ajax for passing list to controller or if any how you want use form posting then maintain 2 hidden @Html.ListBoxFor list & bind it with model & modified their value using jquery on change of your actual list (jquery sortable list)

Answer (score 0):

the form requires `<input>` to submit its values to controller

you can use hidden input if you don't want to use list box

```
<input id="hiddenInput" name="SelectedColumns" type="hidden" value="" />
```

**input name must be exactly same as model*

then update selected values using jquery

```
$(function () { 
    $("#SelectedColumns, #RemainingColumns").sortable({ 
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable" ,
        update: function() {
            var selectedValues = $("#SelectedColumns").serialize(); //get selected values
            $('#hiddenInput').val(selectedValues); //update hidden input
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```